# Apple Watch4 with OS6 slow/ unresponsive on tap to wake

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I’ve been using Apple Watch Series 4 with Watch OS 5.x for a year. With disabled raise to wake I had no problems with waking the watch by tapping the screen.

Upon upgrade to Watch OS6, I now need multiple taps to wake. Single tap does not even get registered most of the time. After it finally wakes up, and I turn the screen off, it wakes back up with one tap. But the initial wake is problematic - takes 3-4 seconds and multiple taps.

I also sanitized the watch band with rubbing alcohol. I wiped the screen too. Would rubbing alcohol damage the tap to wake ability?

How do I restore single tap to wake on Apple Watch with WatchOS6.0.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue with a lot of people experiencing it in [this Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250684724?answerId=251315001022#251315001022). There is no fix of it as of yet, but as people have complained Apple is aware of it and should release a fix soon. So now all you can do is wait for an update.